# All Twitter tweets on page rendered event/callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, tweets

I am working with this [code](http://martinwolf.org/2015/02/02/detect-if-embedded-tweet-has-been-loaded/).

```
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    // At this point the widget.js file had been loaded.
    // We can now make use of the twttr events
    twttr.events.bind('rendered', function (event) {
         // At this point the tweet as been fully loaded
         // and rendered and you we can proceed with our Javascript
        console.log("Created widget", event.target.id);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, the 'rendered' event will fire separately for each of the tweets, is there a proper way to be **notified when all** the embedded tweets on a page are rendered/displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I have found the proper solution. You need to listen for the ['loaded' event](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events), which will trigger only after all tweet widgedts are displayed.

```
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    // At this point the widget.js file had been loaded.
    // We can now make use of the twttr events
    twttr.events.bind('loaded', function (event) {
         // At this point all tweets have been fully loaded
         // and rendered and you we can proceed with our Javascript
        console.log("Created widget", event.target.id);
    });
});
```